# How to run Qt application from Visual Studio 2019 targeting WSL

Tags: visual-studio, qt, debugging, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a CMake Qt project targeting WSL set up and working fine in VS2019, however when I try to debug the program it *probably* terminates because it can not connect to any X display - I say probably, because I could not find a way of how to check console output of the app as the Linux Console Window immediately closes after the app crashes.

I have VcXsrv up and running - when I run the compiled app from WSL it works just fine.

How to set up environment for VS to be actually able to run and debug an X app?

**EDIT:**

It does not help if I set DISPLAY environment variable in CMakeFiles.txt using     SET(ENV{DISPLAY} "0.0") nor SET(ENV{DISPLAY} ":0.0").

**What I have tried so far:**

cMakeSettings.json - "environments": [ { "DISPLAY": ":0.0" } ], - NOT WORKING

SET(ENV{DISPLAY} ":0.0") in CMakeFiles.txt for solution - NOT WORKING

SET(ENV{DISPLAY} ":0.0") in CMakeFiles.txt for target - NOT WORKING

WSLENV - NOT WORKING because of too old Win10 build

tasks.vs.json - implement envVars:{DISPLAY:":0.0"} - NOT WORKING

**EDIT:**

Problem lies within WSL. Installing Ubuntu into VM made it work flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

try to use [Xming](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/) X Server for Windows